# Laptop to monitor doesn't display 1920x1080

Tags: laptop, display

So I got this laptop recently and it's resolution is 1920x1080 and I'm trying to hook it up to a monitor, the monitor does support 1920x1080 it even says it's currently set to it. Everything on the laptop says it should be 1920x1080, I have no problem changing the setting to it but it clearly does not display 1020x1080, I recently had an older laptop hooked up on the monitor and that displayed 1920x1080 and it's a huge difference.

I've screenshotted it and c+pd into paint and the dimensions were 1920x1080 so I have no clue on why it doesn't display it that way. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If possible, please provide a screenshot on the troubled monitor and also update the question with your OS.  Could help us troubleshoot with you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it. It displayed everything at 125% from factory for some reason

Comment: Sounded like display scaling.